# Real Analysis ans

Tags: real-analysis

Show that 
sup$\{x \in \mathbb Q: x > 0, x^2 < 2\} = \sqrt2. $
I am solve this question I just want to know my ans is right or need to improve it.

**Ans:**
Let $A=\{x \in \mathbb Q: x > 0, x^2 < 2\} $

We have $ x \in \mathbb Q: x > 0, x^2 < 2$

i.e $0<x^2<2 $

$ 0<x<\sqrt2$
$\implies$ for all x in A there is l.u.b which is $\sqrt2$
$\implies$$\sqrt2$ is sup of set A

Comment: What you need to show is two things: (1) $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $A$, and (2) if $u$ is some other upper bound of $A$, then $\sqrt{2} \leq u$.

Comment: okay I can show that $\sqrt2$ is upper bound of A now how to show that (2)

Comment: just try to prove (2) by contradiction. use that $x^2<2$

Answer (score 2):

You have shown that $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $A$. You need to show that it is the least upper bound. To do this, suppose that $b$ is an upper bound of $A$ but $b < \sqrt{2}$. Can you find $x \in A$(Equiv. $x^2 < 2$) such that $x > b$?